# full screen width slideshow

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have problem making a slideshow to full screen. In my home.html.erb i have this code:

```
<div class="containerfull">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
.mySlides {display:none; background-size: cover;}
</style>


<div class="containerfull" style="background-size: cover;">
<img class="mySlides" src="https://imagejournal.org/wp-content/uploads/bb- 
plugin/cache/23466317216_b99485ba14_o-panorama.jpg" style="width:100%">
</div>

<script>
var myIndex = 0;
carousel();

function carousel() {
var i;
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
   x[i].style.display = "none";
}
myIndex++;
if (myIndex > x.length) {myIndex = 1}
x[myIndex-1].style.display = "block";
setTimeout(carousel, 2000); // Change image every 2 seconds
}
</script>

</div>
```

i set the image to width: 100% and also made a div containerfull with width: 100%.

But when i reload the browser and inspect my site my home.html.erb code is placed inside a div container with width: 80%. But i don't have this div container in my home.html.erb code. 
I can't figure out where this div comes from and therefore can't change anything about the 80%.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to put your style stuff is a .css file.. But here is what I did and it worked..

```
<img class="mySlides" src="https://imagejournal.org/wp-content/uploads/bb-plugin/cache/23466317216_b99485ba14_o-panorama.jpg" style="min-width:100%; height:50%; position:fixed; top: 0; left: 0;"/>
```

1. Instead of width, I did `min-width:100%;`..
2. Added `height:50%;` (Not sure what you wanted for that)..
3. Added `position:fixed;`
4. Added `top:0;`
5. Added `left:0;`